# Encoding pcm and decoding opus data using libopus in C

Tags: c, openal, opus

I'm trying to encode incoming pcm data from hardware with libopus and then decode it using the same library but the result I'm getting is `decoded.raw` can be played using `aplay -t raw --rate=48000 --buffer-size=1920 --channels=1 --format=FLOAT_LE decoded.raw` command, but it's still just a white noise. `test.raw` file can be played with the same previous command just fine, no issues. But `test.opus` file can't be played in any manner whatsoever. Not sure what am I missing here, the data is being written just fine in `test.raw` so it's not a problem with recording strategy I think.

```
#include <string>
#include <AL/al.h>
#include <AL/alc.h>
#include <AL/alext.h>
#include <opus/opus.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE* raw = fopen("test.raw", "w");
    FILE* opus = fopen("test.opus", "w");
    FILE* decoded = fopen("decoded.raw", "w");
    int i = 0;
    size_t capture_frequency = 48000;
    size_t samples_size = capture_frequency/25;
    int channels_length = 1;

    int error;
    OpusEncoder* encoder = opus_encoder_create(capture_frequency, 1, OPUS_APPLICATION_VOIP, &error);

    if(error != OPUS_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to create codec\n");
    }

    const ALCchar* deviceName = alcGetString(NULL, ALC_CAPTURE_DEFAULT_DEVICE_SPECIFIER);
    ALCdevice* device = alcCaptureOpenDevice(deviceName, capture_frequency, AL_FORMAT_MONO_FLOAT32, samples_size);

    if(device == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open device\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Opened capture device \"%s\"\n", alcGetString(device, ALC_CAPTURE_DEFAULT_DEVICE_SPECIFIER));

    alcCaptureStart(device);

    OpusDecoder* decoder = opus_decoder_create(capture_frequency, channels_length, &error);

    if(error != OPUS_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to create decoder\n");

    while(alcGetError(device) == ALC_NO_ERROR && i < 1000){
        ALCint availableSamples = 0;
        alcGetIntegerv(device, ALC_CAPTURE_SAMPLES, 1, &availableSamples);

        if(availableSamples < samples_size)
            continue;

        float* buffer = (float*)malloc(samples_size*channels_length*sizeof(float));
        alcCaptureSamples(device, buffer, samples_size);

        printf("got %d samples, we needed %d\n", samples_size, samples_size);

        unsigned char* output = (unsigned char*) malloc(4000);
        int bytes_written = opus_encode_float(encoder, buffer, samples_size, output, 4000);

        if(bytes_written < 0){
            if(bytes_written == OPUS_BAD_ARG)
                fprintf(stderr, "invalid args\n");
            else
                fprintf(stderr, "failed to encode\n");
            continue;
        } else {
            printf("got output from encoder %d\n", bytes_written);
        }
        fwrite(output, bytes_written, 1, opus);

        float* output_pcm = (float*) malloc(samples_size*sizeof(float));
        int decoded_bytes = opus_decode_float(decoder, output, bytes_written, output_pcm, samples_size, 1);

        if(decoded_bytes < 1)
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to decode bytes\n");
        else {
            printf("%d bytes decoded\n", decoded_bytes);
        }

        fwrite(output_pcm, samples_size*sizeof(float), 1, decoded);
        fwrite(buffer, samples_size*sizeof(float), 1, raw);
        i++;
    }

    fclose(opus);
    fclose(raw);
    fclose(decoded);
    alcCaptureStop(device);
    alcCaptureCloseDevice(device);
    opus_decoder_destroy(decoder);
    opus_encoder_destroy(encoder);
}
```

Comment: I'm curious are you decoding the same number of bytes that you recorded to your raw buffer?  If you can post a link to those two files I'd be willing to have a look.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot decode file.opus because you need some container to OPUS codec. This is important because OPUS is packet-oriented format. So it cannot decode stream of bytes. It can decode stream of packets.

When you write packets to file one by one you loose packets boundaries and there is no way to restore them.

You can choose one of possible formats:

- ogg
- matroska

I think you can easily find convenient library to write them.